# Configure link to Survey123 for browser

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I'm tring to create a link to survey123 on browser.

I've been able to configure link for the app.
Link has become:

```
arcgis-survey123://?itemID=XXXXXXXX&field:ObjID=1&center=9.999,9.999
```

But web (Surveylink) version does not work. I can’t set center.

This does **not** work:

```
https://survey123.arcgis.com/share/XXXXXXX?field:ObjID=1&field:center=9.999,9.999
```

How can I set up my center for browser version?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I use Firefox. But it something esri does not allow I thing

Answer (score 1):

When using the `center` parameter, you should not add `field:` in front of it. You've got the parameters right for the app, but you have them wrong when invoking the web app.
Replace `field:center` with just `center` and your url will work just fine.